# JQuery method for IFrame functionality

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have a aspx page (details page) that needs to be loaded in a modal window on a click of a button. I have buttons in the aspx page that calls server side functionality. So, this is similar to an IFrame way (except that it's now in a modal window)

Is there a JQuery way of doing this? It appears that the JQuery `load` loads only fragments of HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an IFRAME in a [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).